# Passing data from Link to a component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a **Component 1** that renders a bunch of anchor links. When a user clicks on this link, it opens up a new page(**Component 2**) where the html structure for this page needs to be passed from **Component 1**. I am currently trying to pass the data from `<Link />` using the `state={}` property.

**Component 1**

```
<Link
  to={{pathname:"...", state:{content:"<div>....</div>"}}}
  target="_blank"
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
  className="..."
/>
```

**Routes.js**

```
.......
<Route path="/somepath/:xyz" exact component={Component 2} />
........
```

At current moment when I inspect for `props.location.state` its "undefined" and not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for me is to pass a `render` prop to my `<Route />`:

```
<Route path="/somepath/:xyz" exact render={(props) => <MyComponent {...props} anotherProp="test" /> />
```

Comment: i did try this, still state is undefined

Comment: State is undefined because you have to access to `props`, then **inside** the component you can use `setState()` or use directly the `props`

Comment: sorry I should have been specific when I console for `this.props.location.state` inside the component its undefined

Comment: Post an updated snippet, this works like a charm in all my projects so there must be a typo or some kind of error in your code because this pattern is very common and I have no doubts about it

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue while I try to access `this.props.location.state`. It gives undefined. Any solution for this problem?